# KeyError: 'date' - I don't know why I keep getting this error

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone help with this error? I am trying to plot high-level charts to get an idea of the various developments in a Covid-19 dataset that I'm using.

```
# Convert date column to datetime type
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

# Group data by quarter and calculate total cases per million
df_total_cases_quarterly = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.quarter).agg({'total_cases_per_million': 'sum'}).reset_index() # df['date'].dt.quarter

# Create bar plot for total cases per million on a quarterly basis
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.barplot(x ='date', y = 'total_cases_per_million', data = df_total_cases_quarterly)
plt.title('Total Cases per Million (Worldwide) - Quarterly')
plt.xlabel('Quarter')
plt.ylabel('Total Cases per Million')
plt.xticks(ticks=[0, 1, 2, 3], labels=['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'])  # Update x-axis labels to show quarters
plt.show()
```

***The error code whenever I run the code given above***

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3628             try:
-> 3629                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3630             except KeyError as err:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'date'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/rf/8yc43r0d13l2gw8m9r17pc7h0000gn/T/ipykernel_942/1110610808.py in <module>
      3 
      4 # Group data by quarter and calculate total cases per million
----> 5 df_total_cases_quarterly = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.quarter).agg({'total_cases_per_million': 'sum'}).reset_index() # df['date'].dt.quarter
      6 
      7 # Create bar plot for total cases per million on a quarterly basis

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3503             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3504                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3505             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506             if is_integer(indexer):
   3507                 indexer = [indexer]

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3629                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3630             except KeyError as err:
-> 3631                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3632             except TypeError:
   3633                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 'date'
```

I grouped a COVID-19 dataset by quarter and calculated the total cases per million so that the result can be displayed using seaborn. Despite date column not missing which I used earlier in the code as seen below and did run successfully, I am not sure why I am getting the error code given above. I would to know what is casing the error and fix it. Thanks for your help!

**This code runs successfully**

```
# Filter data for daily new deaths per million
df_daily_new_deaths = df.groupby('date').agg({'new_deaths_per_million': 'sum'}).reset_index()

# Create line plot for daily new deaths per million
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.lineplot(x = 'date', y = 'new_deaths_per_million', data = df_daily_new_deaths)
plt.title('Daily New Deaths per Million (Worldwide)')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Daily New Deaths per Million')
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as caused by a typo / not reproducible. [code execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIiZM.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work fine, accessing [`dt.quarter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.quarter.html) shouldn't change the column name. You are probably doing something else that you are not reporting here. Or maybe using an old version of pandas with a bug?

This was tested both on python 3.8 + pandas 1.5.2 and on python 3.11 + pandas 2.0.0.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# set up dummy data
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-04-01', '2023-07-01', '2023-10-01']*5,
                   'total_cases_per_million': np.random.random(20),
                  })
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)


# running your exact code

import seaborn as sns

# Group data by quarter and calculate total cases per million
df_total_cases_quarterly = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.quarter).agg({'total_cases_per_million': 'sum'}).reset_index() # df['date'].dt.quarter
df_total_cases_quarterly

sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.barplot(x ='date', y = 'total_cases_per_million', data = df_total_cases_quarterly)
plt.title('Total Cases per Million (Worldwide) - Quarterly')
plt.xlabel('Quarter')
plt.ylabel('Total Cases per Million')
plt.xticks(ticks=[0, 1, 2, 3], labels=['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'])  # Update x-axis labels to show quarters
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign column date by quarters before `groupby`:

```
df_total_cases_quarterly = (df.assign(date=df['date'].dt.quarter)
                              .groupby('date')
                              .agg({'total_cases_per_million': 'sum'})
                              .reset_index()
```

Or change index name by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df_total_cases_quarterly = (df.groupby(df['date'].dt.quarter)
                              .agg({'total_cases_per_million': 'sum'})
                              .rename_axis('date')
                              .reset_index()
```